# Neo4j Scalability

Tags: neo4j, nosql, bigdata, scalability

I have read this [article](http://na-sjl.marketo.com/rs/neotechnology/images/Understanding%20Neo4j%20Scalability%282%29.pdf). It states, that Neo4j can scale horizontally, but only to increase read performance and fault tolerance... so the stored graph is copied to each server in a cluster. But what if I have a dataset that is larger than one server can store? Does Neo4j fail in this situation? Do I have to scale vertically in this situation and buy larger HDD?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need enough hard drive space to contain the full graph on all nodes of the cluster, no way around that.

If you're instead referring to RAM instead of hard drive space, then it isn't necessary to have all of the db in memory (defined by the pagecache setting in neo4j.conf), but that will mean you'll hit the disk on all pagecache misses.

Here's the [memory configuration section](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/memory-configuration/) in the docs for details.

Comment: Note that as of the 4.0.0 release at the start of 2020, we introduced [Neo4j Fabric](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/fabric/introduction/) a solution for sharded/federated graphs. This allows sharding out your graph among separate instances/clusters and being able to query across them via the proxy server.